# How to evaluate $\lim _{x\to 0}\left(\frac{1-\cos\left(2x\right)}{2x^2}\right)^{\frac{1}{x^2}}$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, limits-without-lhopital

$$\lim _{x\to 0}\left(\frac{1-\cos\left(2x\right)}{2x^2}\right)^{\frac{1}{x^2}}$$
I have a problem with this limit, I have no idea how to compute it. Can you explain the method and the steps used(without L'Hopital if is possible)? Thanks

I tried to solve like that:(Taylor)
$$e^{\frac{1}{x^2}\ln\left(\frac{1-\cos\left(2x\right)}{2x^2}\right)}$$
$$\ln\left(\frac{1-\cos\left(2x\right)}{2x^2}\right)=\ln\left(\frac{1-1+2x^2-\frac{2x^4}{3}}{2x^2}\right)=\ln\left({1-\frac{2x^4}{9x^2}}\right)$$

$$\frac{1}{x^2}\left(-\frac{2x^4}{9x^2}\right)=\color{red}{e^{-\frac{2}{9}}}$$
Which however it is wrong.
The result sought is $\color{red}{e^{-1/3}}$

Comment: $(2-2/3)/2=1-1/3$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You made a mistake at the second equality: how did $\frac{2x^2 - \frac{2x^4}{3}}{2x^2}$ become $1- \frac{2x^4}{9x^2}$? It should be a $6$, not a $9$ — and then you'll get the correct limit.

But besides this, be careful: for what you write to be correct, *do not forget to include the $o(\cdot)$'s in the Taylor expansions*! Without them, this is rigorously wrong, and also an open invitation to many mistakes (since it's not explicit to anyone, including you, what order becomes negligible.)

Comment: OMGGGGGGGGGGGGG :) Thanks

Comment: @ClementC., is there any sufficient method involving $$\frac{1-\cos(2x)}{2x^2}=\frac{\sin^2x}{x^2}?$$